# Parse JSON array using Unix tools

Tags: json, unix

```json
[
 {"key":"server","value":"10.1.1.1"},
 {"key":"file","value":"test.yaml"},
 {"key":"permissions","value":"755"}
]
```

I have following JSON stored in a variable. How can I iterate over the JSON array in Bash script and extract `key` and `value` pairs using standard Unix tools like `sed` or `awk`? I can't use any other tool like `jq`. I am new to shell script so having a hard time understanding how to achieve this. Desired output is:

```sh
key is: server
value is: 10.1.1.1
key is: file
value is: test.yaml
key is: permissions
value is: 755
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: awk -F[\"] '/key/ && /value/ { print $4":"$8 }'

Comment: sed -rn 's/(^.*\{"key":")(.*)(","value":")(.*)("\},?$)/\2:\4/p'

Comment: sed doesn't return anything and awk only returns first line `server:10.1.1.1`

Comment: @colossal, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question it's highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: sure. reading the awk and sed documentation

Comment: Can you use perl or python at least?

Comment: the thing is the container where the script will be ran comes with minimal set of libraries. Not sure about perl and python but will look into that too

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$keyval"

[
   {"key":"server","value":"10.1.1.1"},
   {"key":"file","value":"test.yaml"},
   {"key":"permissions","value":"755"}
]


awk -F[\"] '/key/ && /value/ { printf "key is: %s\nvalue is: %s\n",$4,$8 }' <<< "$keyval"
```

Read the text as a variable keyval, enclosing it in quotes to take account of line feeds. Then search for lines with key and value and print the 4th and 8th quote delimited fields in the format outlined.

```
key is: server
value is: 10.1.1.1
key is: file
value is: test.yaml
key is: permissions
value is: 755

sed -rn 's/(^.*\{"key":")(.*)(","value":")(.*)("\},?$)/key is: \2\nvalue is: \4/p' <<< "$keyval"
```

Again with sed, read the variable keyval in, and split each line into 5 sections. Substitute these sections for the 2nd and 4th sections only, printed in the format required.

```
key is: server
value is: 10.1.1.1
key is: file
value is: test.yaml
key is: permissions
value is: 755
```